# Pandas: How to split and read values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my dataset, there is a column that has names of the courses taken by a student. It has multiple values

My data set is like this:
[current dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lbUJ.png)

I want change it to a dataset like this:
[wantDatasetLikethis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0QWM.png)

I want to separate these values (course names) and create column for each course separately and assign values 1 or 0 based on the courses taken by a student. How can I do that using Pandas library ?

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Please add a sample data frame to your post as text. @S Ra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the sample dataframe using data that you gave

```
  StudentID                    Courses
0        S1  course1, course2, course3
1        S2  course1, course4, course5
```

Split the courses column

```
df['Courses'] = df.Courses.str.split(', ')

  StudentID                      Courses
0        S1  [course1, course2, course3]
1        S2  [course1, course4, course5]
```

Explode the courses column

```
df = df.explode('Courses')

  StudentID  Courses
0        S1  course1
0        S1  course2
0        S1  course3
1        S2  course1
1        S2  course4
1        S2  course5
```

Use get_dummies to create a separate column for each course

```
pd.get_dummies(df.explode('Courses'), columns=['Courses'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')

  StudentID  course1  course2  course3  course4  course5
0        S1        1        0        0        0        0
0        S1        0        1        0        0        0
0        S1        0        0        1        0        0
1        S2        1        0        0        0        0
1        S2        0        0        0        1        0
1        S2        0        0        0        0        1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. I dont want to repeat StudentIDs in rows. A student id should appear only once

Comment: Use `df.set_index('StudentID')` @SRa

Comment: Thanks. SetIndex is not helping. I want data to be in this format. Please see the picture given in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
header_list = ['StudentID','Courses','Course1', 'Course2']

df = df.reindex(columns = header_list)
```

This will include those columns into the dataframe. Including empty columns.